# Attribute that implies different foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I've faced with a problem while studied databases.
Suppose there are relations:

```
SomeEntity (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CompletelyAnotherEntity (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
);

Competition (
  competitor1 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SomeEntity, 
  competitor2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CompletelyAnotherEntity
  winner FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ???
);
```

What type should has `winner` attribute in the `Competition` relation? What should it reference?

I came up with a solution of defining two attribute `winner1` references `SomeEntity` and `winner2` references `CompletelyAnotherEntity`. One of them can be `null`, but both simultaneously cannot be defined. I think it is not a correct solution, so help me resolve this issue properly.

Comment: I would use a boolean, like 'isWinnerCompetitor1'.  The problem with adding another competitor (entity) is you aren't guaranteed it will match either entered value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two relation variables for `GladiatorWinsCompetition` and `AnimalWinsCompetition` respectively (you could get away with having just one and inferring the other).

Cleaning up your schema a little (use more useful entity names, make attribute names consistent across relvars, always include data types):

```
Gladiator (
  GladiatorId int PRIMARY KEY
);

Animal (
  AnimalId int PRIMARY KEY
);

Competition (
  GladiatorId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Gladiator, 
  AnimalId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Animal,
  PRIMARY KEY ( GladiatorId, AnimalId )
);

GladiatorWinsCompetition (
  GladiatorId int, 
  AnimalId int,
  PRIMARY KEY ( GladiatorId, AnimalId ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( GladiatorId, AnimalId ) REFERENCES Competition
);

AnimalWinsCompetition (
  GladiatorId int, 
  AnimalId int,
  PRIMARY KEY ( GladiatorId, AnimalId ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( GladiatorId, AnimalId ) REFERENCES Competition
);
```

Comment: Maybe with just `GladiatorWinsCompetition` and `AnimalWinsCompetition` you can infer `Competition` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time thinking of a competition that has *two different* entities competing.  I would expect something like this:

```
Competitors (
  CompetitorId int PRIMARY KEY
);

Competition (
  competitor1 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Competitors(CompetitorId), 
  competitor2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Competitors(CompetitorId),
  winner FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Competitors(CompetitorId)
);
```

Comment: Actually, they are different entities. For example, gladiators and animals in Colosseum.

Comment: @0x1337 . . . Or there are just two different attributes on `Competitor`.

Comment: So the winner must be a competitor in some competition but not necessarily the competition in question?! e.g. in "man vs dog, the winner is cat" doesn't make sense to me. P.S. one of your relvars has no key.

Answer (score 0):

```
competitor(id)
gladiator(id) -- FK to competitor
animal(id) -- FK to competitor
competition(gid,aid,cid) -- FKs to gladiator, animal & competitor
```

If the DBMS cannot give you the column union type you need, have

```
gladiator(id,gtype)
animal(id,atype)
```

This also serves if the external language types of gladiators and/or animals are/is not a native DBMS where type, gtype or atype can be representations of them in some native DBMS type.

Observe how being in a given table is a way for a value to be typed independently of a DBMS or external type system.

Comment: I don't understand your answer at all e.g. if `id` in `gladiator` is the same as `id` in competitor then an animal can be a gladiator? You don't even mention the word 'win' (or derivatives).

Comment: @onedaywhen It doesn't matter what columns are *called*. It matters what the tables mean. The interpretations are supposed to be obvious. competition(gid,aid,cid) "gladiator *gid* competed against animal *aid* and the winner is *cid*". I don't understand "if id in gladiator is the same as id in competitor then an animal can be a gladiator?"

Comment: "gladiator gid competed..." there is no `gid` in relvar `gladiator` it only has `id` so does `gid` change its name to `id` when in `gladiator`... but thought that the `id` in `gladiator` was actually `id` from `competitor` because **I assumed** you mean that `gladiator` "is a" `competitor` i.e. subclass -> superclass. And in your schema what stops the absurd predicate "gladiator 'man' competed against animal 'dog' and the winner is 'cat'"? So for me your answer isn't obvious!

Comment: ...not trying to give you a hard time: I think this can be made to work (if I've understood correctly) by a tuple constraint such as `CHECK ( cid IN ( gid,aid ) )` - I can sketch this out for you if you like :)

Comment: Yes I meant is-a, T(id) "*id* identifies a T". But my design doesn't address how competitor is kept the disjoint union of gladiator & animal. I stilll don't know why you care what columns are called; what matters is what a row states via its values. If there are only those two types of competitors then the CHECK is unneeded. (Rather like your answer being hardwired for two types.) (Yours doesn't prevent 2 or 0 winners). I'm all for just competition(c1,c2,is_winner_1). Too bad one must pervert SQL schemas seeking declarative constraints. I'll likely delete this answer rather than improve it.

Comment: "I stilll don't know why you care what columns are called" - I don't: I just care they preserve their names though-out the schema. Try doing some natural joins and you will discover what I'm getting at. "Yours doesn't prevent 2 or 0 winners" - this is by design: 0 winners is a fixture not yet held, 2 winners is a draw :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to make winner reference anything ?

CHECK (winner in (competitor1, competitor2)) is what you really need.  Winner as an FK to anything would still leave room for competitor3 to be the winner of (competitor1,competitor2).  Does that seem reasonable to you ?

EDIT

I've deliberately ignored the issue of scheduled/ongoing competitions that do already have known competitors, but not yet a known winner.